# Understanding the proof of this theorem leading up to Dedekind's theorem

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, proof-explanation

I am reading Murty & Esmonde's *Problems in Algebraic Number Theory* and was wondering if anyone can offer some clarification on the proof of this theorem:

> Let $p \in \mathbb{Z}$ be prime and $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime ideal of $\mathcal{O}_K$ and $\mathcal{D}$ the different of $K$. If $\mathfrak{p}^e \mid (p)$ then $\mathfrak{p}^{e-1} \mid D$.

The basic idea of the proof is to show $p^{-1}\mathfrak{p}\mathfrak{a} \subset \mathcal{D}^{-1}$, where $(p) = \mathfrak{p}^e\mathfrak{a}$. The proof begins by taking $x \in \mathfrak{p}\mathfrak{a}$ and showing $x^{p^m} \in \mathfrak{p}^e$ for sufficiently large $m$ (how?) and then claims this implies $x^{p^m} \in \mathfrak{p}^e\mathfrak{a} = (p)$. I don't see the reasoning behind either of these steps.

They next claim that $\text{Tr}(x^{p^m}) \in p\mathbb{Z}$. I'm not sure why this is true. Does a principal ideal always contain the trace of its elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x \in \mathfrak{p} \mathfrak{a}$ implies that $x = \sum_{i=1}^n p_i a_i$, for some $p_i \in \mathfrak{p}, a_i \mathfrak{a}$. Then, by binomial expansion, iteratively taking $p$th powers doesn't change anything mod $p$ (in particular it doesn't change anything mod $\mathfrak{p}$).

Taking $p^m > e$, you get $x^{p^m} \equiv \sum_{i=1}^n p_i^{p^m} a_i^{p^m} \pmod p$. Since each $p_i^{p^m} \in \mathfrak{p}^e$, and $x^{p^m}$ differs from this sum by some element of $(p) \subseteq \mathfrak{p}$, you get $x^{p^m} \in \mathfrak{p}$. Moreover, $x \in \mathfrak{a}$ implies that $\mathfrak{a} \mid (x)$, hence $\mathfrak{a} \mid (x^{p^m})$. Since $\gcd(\mathfrak{a}, \mathfrak{p}) = 1$, we get $(p) = \mathfrak{p}^{e} \mathfrak{a} \mid (x^{p^m})$, which is precisely what it means for $x^{p^m}$ to be in $(p)$.

A principal ideal certainly does not necessarily contain the traces of its elements. Consider the case of a principal ideal in a (imaginary) quadratic field generated by some nonrational element $\alpha$. The trace $\alpha + \alpha'$ of the generator is contained in the ideal if and only if its Galois conjugate $\alpha'$ is also in the ideal. But this would imply that $\alpha, \alpha'$ differ by a unit, which can't happen if you have an imaginary quadratic field with group of units equal to $\{\pm 1\}$.

However, if an ideal is Galois stable, then it will contain the traces of all elements (principality is unnecessary here). In particular, for any $\alpha \in I \subseteq \mathcal{O}_K$ and any $\sigma \in \mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbf{Q})$, $\sigma(\alpha) \in \sigma(I)$. Hence if an ideal is Galois stable, then all conjugates of a fixed element lie in the ideal, hence their sum (the trace) does as well.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. Just one more question, why does $x^{p^m} \in (p)$ imply $\text{Tr}(x^{p^m}) \in p\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: That's what the last paragraph is about. $(p)$ is Galois stable, so $x^{p^m} \in (p)$ implies that $\mathrm{Tr}(x^{p^m}) \in (p) = p \mathcal{O}_K$. Since the trace is rational, this must actually be in $p \mathcal{O}_K \cap \mathbf{Q} = p \mathbf{Z}$.

Comment: Oh, I'm not familiar with the concept of Galois stable. Thanks

Comment: An ideal $I$ being Galois stable just means that $\sigma(I) = I$ for all $\sigma \in \mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbf{Q})$.

Comment: OK so any ideal generated by $p  \in \mathbb {Q} $ is Galois stable?

Comment: Exactly! $\sigma(I) = \{\sigma(\alpha) \, | \, \alpha \in I\}$, so if $p \in \mathbf{Q}$, $\sigma((p)) = \{\sigma(p \cdot \alpha) \, | \, \alpha \in \mathcal{O}_K\} = \{p \cdot \sigma (\alpha) \, | \, \alpha \in \mathcal{O}_K\} = p \mathcal{O}_K = (p)$.